# Por que os pacotes começam com o prefixo br.com no Java?

Tags: java

Frequentemente observo exemplos na internet de códigos em Java onde sua organização de classes sempre está contida em pacotes com prefixo br.com.algumNomeDePacote. Por que é utilizado o "br.com" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Sun, empresa que criou a linguagem e a plataforma Java, criou uma convenção de nomenclatura para evitar colisões de nomes.

Suponha que você tenha criado uma biblioteca para lidar com geolocalização. O seu programa tem um pacote chamado `GPS`. O pacote tem várias classes e uma delas se chama `Coordenada`.

Agora suponha que eu tenha criado uma biblioteca para deputar leitura de sinal de GPS. Eu crio um pacote chamado `GPS`, que tem várias classes. Uma das minhas classes no pacote se chama `Coordenada`.

Se alguém incluir nossos dois pacotes em uma mesma aplicação, o que acontecerá? Como a aplicação saberá a qual código `GPS.Coordenada` se refere, o do seu pacote ou do meu?

A sugestão da Sun foi que se utilizasse como prefixo de nome de pacote o domínio da empresa que detém o código, para evitar colisões de nomes... Pois é impossível duas empresas terem o exato mesmo domínio. A inversão do domínio é só uma decisão estética.

A documentação dessa convenção pode ser encontrada no site da Oracle, a atual dona do Java. Segue o link (em inglês):

[Naming a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

As empresas brasileiras seguem o padrão e colocam o trecho `br` na frente.

.NET tem o mesmo problema de risco de colisão de nomes desde a sua concepção, mas o pessoal da Microsoft resolveu de outra forma. Você pode dar apelidos a namespaces para evitar colisões. Por isso em .NET as bibliotecas não costumam usar nomes de domínios, mas apenas os nomes das empresas.

Finalmente, o que fazer quando o código não é de uma empresa, mas sim algo pessoal, ou pelo menos de algo ou alguém que não tem domínio? Bom, nesse caso, <strike>* no seu *</strike> a documentação não diz nada. Assim como uma empresa é livre para não seguir a convenção, nesse caso você é livre para nomear seus pacotes como achar melhor.